# jQuery: animate() on social media icons

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I have a set of 5 social media icons on the bottom of my website and when I try to animate them using `animate()`, the animation works on the hovered-over icon but all of the other icons move as well. Any ideas how to fix this?

This is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('footer img').hover(function(){
    $(this).animate({width:'55px', height:'55px'}, 'fast');
      }, function(){
    $(this).animate({width:'50px', height:'50px'}, 'fast');
  });
});
```

This is the styling I used for the icons in the footer:

```
.footer img{
  position: relative;
  width: 50px;
  margin-top: 100px;
  margin-right: 1.5em;
  margin-left: 1.5em;
}
```

Comment: I think that is because your selector is wrong : you used `footer img` instead of `.footer img`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```js
    $(document).ready(function(){
    
    $('.footer img').hover(function(){
        $(this).animate({width:'55px', height:'55px'}, 'fast');
          }, function(){
        $(this).animate({width:'50px', height:'50px'}, 'fast');
      });
    });
```

```css
 .footer div {
     display:inline-block;
     height:70px;
     width:70px;
    }
    
    .magicClass{
     display:inline-block;
     height:70px;
     width:5px;
    }
    .footer img{
      position: relative;
      width: 50px;
    
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <body>
    
    <div class="footer" style="height:1000px">
     <div>
      <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/images/colorpicker.gif"/>
     </div>
     <div class="magicClass"></div>
     <div>
      <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/images/colorpicker.gif"/>
     </div>
     <div class="magicClass"></div>
     <div>
      <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/images/colorpicker.gif"/>
     </div>
    </div>

    </body>
```